# "Click" button of a program from an application I'm building

Tags: c#

**Boring background**:
I have been working with UltraVNC to control some PC's at work and it does the job great but in order to simplify things I created a program that interfaces with it in C#. Basically I take advantage of the commands the viewer offers to connect, control, watch or transmit to each PC.

Problem is anyone can access the PC's since it has one main account (no domain controller). I need everyone to sign for the PC before they can use it, so to make my job easier I open each PC and block the inputs + blank the screen that way there obligated to sign before use.

Opening each pc and press the block button can be hassle especial when you’re helping someone and a user leaves, others come (btw I work at an electronic library). UltraVNC doesn’t have a command for this; it’s been requested but I don’t think it’s much of a priority for them and the code seems very intimidating for a novice like me so I thought I could try a hack to get what I want.

**Problem**: I want to “click” a button in a program I use, from an application that I am building in c#. I can currently use the process class to get the handle and identify the specific window I want to use but I have no way to find the button handle which I read is what I need. I found stuff about using findwindow and sendkeys for this but I don’t see how that’ll work unless the button had a keystroke assigned to it which it doesn’t.
So can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I tried WinID but all it could detect was the toolbar, it did identify the image but I don't that will be of much help. Maybe a lost cause oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something like [Eficium Cybercafe SurfShop](http://www.dynasoft.net/surfshop/) to achieve what you want? After teh user finished you log the session out, and before someone can log in, they have to sign in.

Comment: Looks interesting if I can get approval to install it but it does seems like a bit much for what I want since I don't need 90% of the stuff in the program.